# Increase Hex2dec or dec2hex output range in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink, hex, uint64

I have a strange problem with hex2dec function in Matlab.
I realized in 16bytes data, it omits 2 LSB bytes.

```
hex2dec('123123123123123A');
dec2hex(ans)
Warning: At least one of the input numbers is larger than the largest integer-valued floating-point
number (2^52). Results may be unpredictable. 
ans =
1231231231231200
```

I am using this in Simulink. Therefore I cannot process 16byte data. Simulink interpret this as a 14byte + '00'.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `uint64` to store that value:

```
A='123123123123123A';
B=bitshift(uint64(hex2dec(A(1:end-8))),32)+uint64(hex2dec(A(end-7:end)))
```

which returns

```
B =

  1310867527582290490
```

Comment: try this in simulink, simulink still gets all data 14bytes + 0x00

Comment: Well your original question didn't mention Simulink. Simulink doesn't have support for uint64 (http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/ug/working-with-data-types.html). You need to treat it as two 32bit chunks.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia Actually the OP did mention Simulink:
"I am using this in Simulink."

I added the Simulink tag to the question early on.

Comment: So they produced HDL coder in simulink and they are not able to work with 64bit data for simulation?

Comment: @am304 I missed that. Sorry!

Comment: @Ramyad From http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/working-with-data-types.html: "Simulink supports all built-in numeric MATLAB data types except int64 and uint64." One can only assume that these will be supported in a future release.

Comment: @am304 Thanks very much. But, can I design a model which deals with 64bits data and convert it using HDL coder properly? I mean if I do not want to simulate it and only want to generate HDL code.

Comment: @Ramyad Not entirely sure, I'm not very familiar with HDL Coder. Better ask MathWorks for a definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way in MATLAB using `typecast`:

```
>> A = '123123123123123A';
>> B = typecast(uint32(hex2dec([A(9:end);A(1:8)])), 'uint64')
B =
  1310867527582290490
```

And the reverse in the opposite direction:

```
>> AA = dec2hex(typecast(B,'uint32'));
>> AA = [AA(2,:) AA(1,:)]
AA =
123123123123123A
```

The idea is to treat the 64-integer as two 32-bit integers.

That said, Simulink [does not support](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/working-with-data-types.html#f14-90488) `int64` and `uint64` types as others have already noted..